# Axios error "Request failed with status code 400" on Mongodb POST request

Tags: mongodb, post, next.js, axios

I’m following a youtube tutorial about mongodb that creates a simple NextJS page and gets only 2 inputs (login and password), and save it in a database on mongodb, but I'm getting that error:

`Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST`

That's my code:

```js
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Home() {
  require("dotenv").config();

  const mongokey = process.env.MONGO_API;

  async function createAccount() {

    const username = document.querySelector("[name=user]").value;
    const email = document.querySelector("[name=email]").value;

    axios
      .post(
        "https://data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-irddk/endpoint/data/v1/action/insertOne",
        {
          collection: "n2D-collection",
          database: "n2D-database",
          dataSource: "Cluster0",
          document: {
            user: username,
            email: email,
          },
        },
        {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "api-key": mongokey,
        }
      )
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log("call failed :", error);

          let displayerror = "Error";
          document.getElementById("displayresult1").innerHTML = displayerror;

          return;
        }
      });

    let displaysuccess = "Account Created Successfully";
    document.getElementById("displayresult1").innerHTML = displaysuccess;
    console.log("username :", username, "email: ", email);
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <h3>Create your account</h3>
        <h5>Create your username</h5>

        <input name="user"></input>

        <h5>Create your email</h5>
        <input name="email"></input>
        <button
          style={{ marginTop: "2px", marginBottom: "2px" }}
          onClick={createAccount}
        >
          Create account
        </button>
        <h2 id="displayresult1"></h2>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The API key is correct, the IP address is allowed on mongodb, also I've tested consoling log the inputs and it's getting correct.

Does anyone know where I'm wrong?

Comment: The `400` error code means you sent the wrong request params, you'd better check API details first. How do you handle the request in the backend?

Comment: Can you post the `/endpoint/data/v1/action/insertOne` endpoint code?

Comment: actually I'm using MongoDB Atlas Data API, that endpoint I got from their dashboard.